# Structure with more Depth vs more breadth in Mongodb overhead

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to store user notifications in mongoDB ( My main database is Mysql ) and the notification table has over 2,500,000 records for each notification.

I want to know that should i store each notification in one row or store them based on user_id, each row containing all notifications of an user. Queries that will perform on these data are selecting all notifications of a user and selecting all notification with notified flag set to false and  updating a flag of a notification with notification id.

Each row on table has id,user_id,description,read,notified

Which one has less overhead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

storing all user's notifications in 1 document is not a good idea,
although **MongoDB** can deal with **nested documents** well, there are some limitations on the document size, **which is 16MB** as [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#:%7E:text=Document%20Size%20Limit,MongoDB%20provides%20the%20GridFS%20API.) said, anyway it all depends on your **use case**, and you are the only one can decide the best scheme for your business, I would advise you to take a look on this **super useful** article from MongoDB Engineers and try to compare your use case with some of this design patterns
[Building with Patterns: A Summary](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-a-summary)

Answer (score 1):

**Store each notification in one row** would be recommended since `query` or `update` would be easier.

Good

```
_id:"1"
user_id: "1",
description: "123",
read: true
```

Only if notifications and fields are less each user.

```
_id:"1",
user_id: "1",
notifications: [ 
{
  _id:"1",
  description: "123",
  read: true
}]
```